# How do I simulate a copy machine transition in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, image-processing, pixel-manipulation

Apple has a [copy machine transition](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) effect that gradually transforms an image into another.  Since transitions are not available in iOS I'm looking for an alternate method in achieving this effect or something similar.  I'm collecting all of my image data in an UInt8 array of pixel colors.  Ideally, I'd like to have the ability to draw individual rows of pixels to the screen at varying intervals to eventually complete a full picture.  Is this possible?  If not, are there any optimal methods for simulating apple's CICopyMachineTransition?

Comment: I'd probably try placing one image behind the other and tweaking the alpha values.  Of course, the problem is that you've got to tell UI to redraw the image often enough for the effect to be visible.  Or maybe slice the image into about 8 bands, so you'd only have to ask to have two bands redrawn at a time.

Comment: I could theoretically set the alpha of each row of pixels gradually, updating the image for every new visible row.  I get the feeling this  might have awful performance since I'm doing specific alterations to every pixel.  The effect I'm going for is a dynamic image alteration using multiple sliders to affect various characteristics such as noise, brightness, focus and color gain.  The image is intended to reflect these changes with the copy machine effect, rather than being instantaneous.  This also means that the image may be changed multiple times in one transition cycle.